# How to loop prompt until the right input is set

Tags: javascript, html

So i want to loop this function so prompt will come up every time the password is wrong and link to google when its right. How do you loop the prompt?

```
var input = prompt("Enter password");

if (input != "Philip") {

alert("Wrong Password")

} else {

window.open("http://google.com")

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prompt user for specific input, loop and prompt until correct input is entered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30767875/prompt-user-for-specific-input-loop-and-prompt-until-correct-input-is-entered)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's easy do it with a while ,see code below:

```
// The first time user have a chance to input their passwd
var input = prompt("Enter password");

// loop checking if they right let they go next 
while (input != "Philip") { 
     alert("Wrong Password")
     var input = prompt("Enter password");
}
// if everything ok , do the rest of thing ~
window.open("http://google.com");
```

Comment: I was wrong, it worked. I just messed up the code. Thank you :D

Comment: But how is the window.open() connected when you type in the input right. Im just wondering. SInce window.open() is outside the while

Comment: The code will run from top to the bottom ~~Once the condition have been check ok, will go next line! this why you can run the `window.open ...`

Comment: Oh. So the while() will just loop and never reach window.open() if the password isnt typed correctly?

Comment: So if i want to add more javascript and to not let them run over each other i should put them inside a function and use the window.onload?

Comment: Yep! BTW, as @Chirag Ravindra say! you should avoid do this in really project! Because it is very annoying to prompt a window ask user input something again and again ...

Comment: I know :) im just experiencing different things to learn. Never really understood the loop commands so you helped me alot!

Comment: Im currently using this to enter a hidden html page that the user will get access to if you type the password in correctly

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not doing that if this is for a professional website as it is considered bad UX. However, if that is not a concern, one way to do this:

```js
var input = prompt('Enter password:');

while(input!=='correct'){
  alert('Wrong password');
  input = prompt('Enter password:');
}

window.location = 'https://google.com';
```

Answer (score 0):

use while.

```
var input;
while(input !== "Philip"){input = prompt("Enter password");}
alert("This message is prompted when Philip is entered.");
window.open("http://google.com");
```